# ExecJS::RuntimeError SyntaxError: unexpected MATH (rails 4)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

i recently started trying Rails so I don't know much yet. 
I developed so far a simple website and now I'm trying to add more features. First of all I tried pure javascript and it failed, then I translated it to coffeescript and right now I keep getting this error. The code is in /sessions.js.coffee

```
  helper = []

  helper.confirmation = ->
    answer = confirm("Wanna visit google?")
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/"  if answer
```

I'm just testing but I got stuck here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If it fails in JavaScript, why would it work in Coffeescript? Is your indentation correct? Did you mean to create an empty function and 2 statements after that? Also your probably want an object not an array. Dunno, many things seem wrong in that little code at first glance...

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the indentation. I assumed javascript didn't work because the file was not js but js.coffee (and after some googling). Yep, I hadn't considered that it should have been an object. Still it does not work. :(